# privacy protection password

Tags: privacy

Different Sims were switched back n forth out of my BluStudio5.0 and now after 3 factory data reset, the lock screen remains asking for a privacy protection password.  I don't have a computer to flash the phone, and u can't find the receipt of purchase to have a replacement phone sent. Is there anything else I can try. And I've also tried every secret code, lock code, and any and all things free of cost for all the most common brands

Answer (score 0):

Well that's not all you can try! There's still one way to get back into your phone. But you must have ADB (Android Debug Bridge) and USB Debugging under Development Settings!

If that's the case connect your phone via USB to your Computer, go to shell and type:

```
adb shell
```

Now you have access to a shell in your phone!
Next you must delete a file named "gesture.key"

```
rm /data/system/*.key
```

Now reboot! If you still see the unlock screen type something random in and it should unlock!